# dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I'm starting Angular2 Learning using this github repo: https://github.com/angular/quickstart

I tried to start the project to be viewed in a browser using npm start. (I've already run npm install). It just shows this error:

```
$ npm start

\> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/kimnicolemontano/quickstart
\> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
     Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
     ** browser-sync config **
     { injectChanges: false,
     files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
     watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
     server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
     dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
     Referenced from: /Users/username/quickstart/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node
     Expected in: flat namespace

     dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
     Referenced from: /Users/username/quickstart/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node
     Expected in: flat namespace

     10:53:50 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

I'm doing this course in udemy https://www.udemy.com/ultimate-angular-2/. I followed the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is caused by your local Node or NPM installation. The best way to fix this is to uninstall and re-install Node and NPM again, then, update them to the latest versions.

To do that, simply do these steps:

- sudo -i
- npm install npm -g
- sudo -i
- npm cache clean -f
- npm install -g n
- n stable

Then afterwards, run these to verify your new versions.

node -v

npm -v